# Why is the wrapper function required for the predicate function in reduce?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I was playing around with the interaction between Array.reduce and Set and I noticed the following strange behavior.

Normally this works:

```js
console.log(
  Set.prototype.add.call(new Set(), 1, 0, [])
);
// Set { 1 }
```

But if I were to combine that with reduce, the following does not work:

```js
console.log(
  [1,2,3].reduce(Set.prototype.add.call, new Set())
);
// TypeError: undefined is not a function
//     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
```

However if I were to wrap the predicate function in a wrapper, this will work:

```js
console.log(
  [1,2,3].reduce((...args) => Set.prototype.add.call(...args), new Set())
);
// Set { 1, 2, 3 }
```

I tried this on different JS engines (Chrome and Safari) and got the same result so its probably not an engine specific behavior. The same applies to a Map object as well. What I can't figure out is why that is the case.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 I'd think, to use `reduce` with a `Set` without passing an extra function to the first parameter to `reduce`

Comment: @user1251380 Note how `Set.prototype.add.call === Function.prototype.call` - `.call` depends on a calling context (a `this`) to be meaningful (as the answer shows). It's not *only* `Set.prototype.add` that requires a calling context of the set to be added to.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Still not following. Why not just pass the result of `.reduce()` to `new Set()`? Given the example input `Set` is not necessary.

Comment: @guest271314 OP's asking why `[1,2,3].reduce(Set.prototype.add.call, new Set())` is throwing an exception when `[1,2,3].reduce((..args) => Set.prototype.add.call(..args), new Set())` isn't when they are equivalent.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Then how come the regular call (first code block) works? Does this mean there's an internal check inside `reduce` that tests if the predicate function has a calling context? I'm guessing the `TypeError: undefined is not a function` is referring to said call context.

Comment: @user1251380 Because in the first code, you're doing `Set.prototype.add.call(`, which means that `.call` is being called with a `this` of `Set.prototype.add`. In contrast, the second code is passing what is essentially `Function.prototype.call` without a `this`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry if this is redudant but there's 2 moving parts here and it'd be easier if 1 of them have a pinned behavior. In the first code block, its clear that it works because during the function invocation, it has all the context. It's essentially `Function.call` but its already bind to `Set.prototype.add` and it receives the Object context and argument. So how does it automatically bind?

Comment: See answer, hope the elaboration makes it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually *two* parts of the script that need the proper calling context (or `this` value) in order to work properly. The first part, which you've already figured out, is that you need to call `Set.prototype.add` with a calling context of the newly created `Set`, by passing that `Set` as the first argument to `.call`:

```
// works:
Set.prototype.add.call(new Set(), 1, 0, []);
// works, args[0] is the new Set:
[1,2,3].reduce((..args) => Set.prototype.add.call(..args), new Set());
```

But the other issue is that the  *`.call`* needs to be called with the approprite calling context. `Set.prototype.add.call` refers to the same function as `Function.prototype.call`:

```js
console.log(Set.prototype.add.call === Function.prototype.call);
```

The function that `Function.prototype.call` calls is based on its calling context. For example

```
someObject.someMethod.call(< args >)
```

The calling context of a function is everything that comes before the final `.` in the function call. So, for the above, the calling context for `.call` is `someObject.someMethod`. That's how `.call` knows which function to run. Without a calling context, `.call` won't work:

```js
const obj = {
  method(arg) {
    console.log('method running ' + arg);
  }
};

// Works, because `.call` has a calling context of `obj.method`:
obj.method.call(['foo'], 'bar');

const methodCall = obj.method.call;
// Doesn't work, because methodCall is being called without a calling context:
methodCall(['foo'], 'bar');
```

The error in the snippet above is somewhat misleading. `methodCall` *is* a function - specifically `Function.prototype.call` - it just doesn't have a calling context, so an error is thrown. This behavior is identical to the below snippet, where `Function.prototype.call` is being called without a calling context:

```js
console.log(typeof Function.prototype.call.call);
Function.prototype.call.call(
  undefined,
);
```

Hopefully this should make it clear that when using `.call`, you need to use it with the proper calling context, or it'll fail. So, to get back to the original question:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(Set.prototype.add.call, new Set());
```

fails because the internals of `reduce` calls `Set.prototype.add.call` without a calling context. It's similar to the second snippet in this answer - it's like if `Set.prototype.add.call` is put into a standalone variable, and then called.

```js
// essential behavior of the below function is identical to Array.prototype.reduce:
Array.prototype.customReduce = function(callback, initialValue) {
  let accum = initialValue;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    accum = callback(accum, this[i]);
    // note: "callback" above is being called without a calling context
  }
  return accum;
};

// demonstration that the function works like reduce:
// sum:
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3].customReduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
);
// multiply:
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 4].customReduce((a, b) => a * b, 1)
);

// your working Set code:
console.log(
  [1,2,3].customReduce((...args) => Set.prototype.add.call(...args), new Set())
);
// but because "callback" isn't being called with a calling context, the following fails
// for the same reason that your original code with "reduce" fails:
[1,2,3].customReduce(Set.prototype.add.call, new Set());
```

In contrast, the

```
(..args) => Set.prototype.add.call(..args)
```

works (in both `.reduce` and `.customReduce`) because the `.call` is being called with a calling context of `Set.prototype.add`, rather than being saved in a variable first (which would lose the calling context).

Answer (score 4):

Without wrapping, your `Set.prototype.add.call` lose its `this` value (wich should be `Set.prototype.add` function, but instead is set to `undefined`).

Try this:

```js
[1,2,3].reduce(Set.prototype.add.call.bind(Set.prototype.add), new Set());
```

See http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch01.html#_extracting_methods